# Orange-red flower with extravagant shape

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this orange-red flower with extravagant shape (width of structure approx. 5-10 cm), encountered on a hot mid-summer day in Central Europe, but perhaps not native to this part of the world?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That must be a type of honeysuckle or Lonicera. It looks just like the ones we have in N. Calif., US, except ours have plainer flowers ranging from white to cream to off-yellow as they age on the vine. I haven't ever seen one with flowers as gorgeous as your variety has. It looks like it might be the type called "goldflame".

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed a honeysuckle, and I'm pretty sure it's Lonicera heckrotii 'Gold Flame' - this name is synonymous with Lonicera 'American Beauty'. It's one of the slightly later flowering ones, usually starting in June/July sometime and going on until end of August/September; also highly fragrant. https://www.crocus.co.uk/plants/_/lonicera--heckrottii-gold-flame/classid.1689